# wget to access password protected dropbox link

Tags: dropbox

I have dropbox link which is password protected.
The format of the link is as follows:

```
www.dropbox.com/s/xyxyxyxy/
```

I have tried the following

```
wget --password "somepassword" 'www.dropbox.com/s/xyxyxyxy/'
```

> but i see some redirection happening and i don't see the file getting
>   downloaded.

How do i download the contents of this folder using wget?
How should i be specifying the password in wget?

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox shared link page takes the password interactively, not as Basic auth, so using the `--password` option won't work.

To download files from Dropbox shared links programmatically, you should use the Dropbox API instead. For this in particular, you would use the /2/sharing/get_shared_link_file endpoint:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_file

Here's how you would use that with curl, for example:

```
curl -vX POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/get_shared_link_file \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
    --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"url\": \"<SHARED_LINK>\",\"link_password\":\"<SHARED_LINK_PASSWORD>\"}"
```

<s>Note: There's currently a known issue with this endpoint though, so it may incorrectly fail with a `shared_link_access_denied` error even if you supply the correct password.  I'll update this answer when that's fixed.</s>

---

Edit: The issue with calling /2/sharing/get_shared_link_file with a password is now fixed and should be working properly.

Comment: I was receiving shared_link_access_denied, then I realized that my app is marked as App folder permission. That means it can only access shared links of files that are inside the App folder. I moved the files to app folder, created the link and the password and it is working fine.